# Sonarqube Maximum Project

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

I have 20 projects all are setup in Jenkins but after build Sonarqube is showing only 6 project's code analysis report.
Any idea why ? Is it because its free ?
I am using Sonar 5.6.4.

Answer (score 0):

The only limits on the number of projects in a SonarQube instance are imposed by your own infrastructure (disk space available to the DB &etc).

This sounds more like a permissions issue than anything else. At a guess you (as Anonymous) don't have "browse" permissions on the other 14 projects. Try logging in to SonarQube as an administrator (or contact your admin) to verify the existence of the missing projects and double-check their (and your) permissions.

If the projects are truly missing from SonarQube they you must return to the Jenkins job logs to see why the initial analyses failed.